# The `px-3` class does not exist. If `px-3` is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a `@layer` directive

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a very simple `tailwind.config.js` file defined as follows:

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
  presets: [],
  darkMode: 'media', // or 'class'
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      sans: ['var(--font-satoshi)', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('tailwind-scrollbar')({ nocompatible: true }),
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
    require('@tailwindcss/forms')
  ],
};
```

And I am using "typescript": "^5.1.6" with my create-react-app.

Now I am seeings these compile errors and no ideas why:

```
ERROR in ./src/screens/settings/Settings.screen.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/screens/settings/Settings.screen.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SyntaxError

(2:3) /home/project/src/screens/settings/Settings.screen.css The `px-3` class does not exist. If `px-3` is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a `@layer` directive.

  1 | ul.list-container {
> 2 |   @apply flex flex-col px-3 md:px-10 pt-4;
    |   ^
  3 | }
  4 |
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: if i am not wrong you should have ``extend: {},`` within your ``theme`` block. As: ``...theme: { extend: {}, fontFamily: {...}, },``

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have missed:

```
@layer components {
 .ul.list-container {
    @apply flex flex-col px-3 md:px-10 pt-4;
 }}
```

Here is an example from docs: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles#extracting-classes-with-apply